# Fast algorithm to determine aperiodicity of irreducible network

Tags: algorithm, networking

I have a large directed graph network with several hundred thousand of vertices and millions of edges. I have used Tarjan algorithm to clean up the network into an irreducible network. I want to know is there any algorithm to fast check if the network is aperiodic or periodic. The goal is to find out the ergodicity of the network.

Comment: I know we can compute the period using gcd of the power of matrix but that requires a lot of matrix power computation.

Comment: Please define "irreducible" and "periodic".  Also Robert Tarjan has created many algorithms; it would help to identify *which one*.

Comment: I am talking in term of Markov Chain. Viewing the matrix as the adjacency matrix of a directed graph, the matrix is irreducible if and only if such directed graph is strongly connected [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducibility_(mathematics)]. periodicity definition can be found here: http://www.randomservices.org/random/markov/Periodicity.html

Comment: Tarjan algorithm can be found in Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm

Comment: Can you prove that statement? What are the condition for aperiodic network?

Comment: The reason I asked for proof is because your statement is incomplete. If all the diagonal entries are non-zero, it does not guarantee the network is aperiodic.

Comment: Please accept my apologies for my wrong (and very rude) comments, which I've now deleted.  I've worked out a solution that should help -- I'll post it soon.

Answer (score 0):

### The idea: Sums of successive powers of eigenvalues

In the following, all chains are assumed to be irreducible.

Given an n by n transition matrix P, create a new matrix A from P by setting every nonzero value to one, and leaving every zero value at zero.  (This step may not actually be necessary, but should reduce numerical problems.)

For any k >= 1, trace(A^k) will be > 0 if and only if there exists a state x such that P^k[x][x] > 0.  This is because no positive integer power of a matrix with all nonnegative entries can produce a negative matrix entry.

According to [this identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_%28linear_algebra%29#Eigenvalue_relationships), trace(A^k) is equal to the sum of the kth powers of all eigenvalues of A, giving a cheap way to "detect" such loops that can be turned into an algorithm.

### The algorithm

**[EDIT 21/6/2017: Added has_loop variable to simulate initially infinite GCD_so_far.]**  As I'll show, all we need to do is:

1. Compute the n eigenvalues of A (perhaps using the [QR algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_algorithm)).
2. Let has_loop = 0.
3. For k from 1 to n:

   - Let s = the sum of the kth powers of the eigenvalues (easily computed lazily from the previous iteration in O(n) time).
   - If s > 0 then:

     - If has_loop = 0 then:

       - Let GCD_so_far = k.
       - Let has_loop = 1.
     - Else:

       - Let GCD_so_far = gcd(GCD_so_far, k).
     - If GCD_so_far = 1 then report "aperiodic" and halt.
4. Report "periodic".

(Note that while the trace must be an integer real number, in general, the eigenvalues themselves may be complex and contain surds, so it's best to use FP arithmetic and tolerance parameters for those "> 0" comparisons.)

First I'll show that, if an irreducible network is aperiodic, then a version of the algorithm above that continues testing sums of successive powers of eigenvalues, with no upper bound on k, will eventually terminate with the correct answer ("aperiodic").  Then I'll show that it suffices to stop after n iterations -- that is, if GCD_so_far > 1 at this point then it will remain > 1 for all higher powers, so we can stop and report "periodic".

### Proof of correctness of unbounded version on aperiodic chains

First, let's call the value of GCD_so_far after processing trace(A^k) g[k], and for convenience imagine that it is infinite (i.e., a product of an infinite number of copies of all prime factors) if no "s > 0" test has succeeded during the first k iterations.

Assume the chain is aperiodic, so there exists some state x and finite set W of walk lengths such that gcd(W) = 1 and A^i(x, x) > 0 for each i in W.  Let w be the largest element in W.  Since the value of d(x) cannot decrease any further by including values higher than w into the GCD, it must be that d(x) = 1.

After w steps of the algorithm, it has computed (in g[w]) the GCD of a set K of walk lengths.  W is a subset of K, since if i is an element of W then A^i(x, x) >= 1, implying that trace(A^i) > 0, in turn implying that i is an element of K.  gcd(X) >= gcd(Y) whenever X is a subset of Y, so here we have gcd(W) = 1 >= gcd(K), implying gcd(K) = 1.  Thus the algorithm will report "aperiodic" and halt at iteration w at the latest.

The above "unbounded" algorithm eventually detects any aperiodic chain if we continue iterating long enough, but will run forever on periodic chains.  To detect the latter (and the former in bounded time), we need an upper bound to the number of iterations needed.  The following proof shows that n iterations always suffice to detect aperiodicity.

### Proof that the bounded version of the algorithm is correct

Observe that

1. g[i] divides i whenever A^i(x, x) > 0 for some state x, and
2. g[i] divides g[j] for all j <= i.

Suppose to the contrary that after completing iteration k = n, we have determined that g[n] >= 2, but that there exists some q > n such that if we were to continue running the algorithm until k = q, we would find that g[q] = 1.  (Since the correctness of the unbounded version of the algorithm on aperiodic chains is already established, this completely characterises the possible failure modes of the bounded version on such chains.)  Let q be minimum possible: specifically, let's assume g[q-1] = z >= 2.

Then there must exist a length-q walk, beginning and ending at some state u, such that gcd(q, z) = 1.  Since a walk of length > n must visit at least n+2 states, either this walk visits v = u at least 3 times, or it visits some other state v != u at least twice.  Either way, the walk contains a cycle incident on some state v that is strictly smaller than the complete walk from u to u (even in the case where v = u).  Let this cycle have length c >= 1.  Then the walk from u to u formed by removing 1 copy of this cycle has length q-c < q.  The cycle itself also forms a walk from v to v of length c.  By minimality of q, we know that g[q-c] >= z, and c < q so g[c] >= z also.  Furthermore, since g[i] divides g[j] for all j <= i ((2) above), then in particular when i = q-1, we get that g[q-c] = az and g[c] = bz for some positive integers a and b (remember that z is just shorthand for g[q-1]).  This implies that gcd(g[q-c], z) = z.  Since A^(q-c)(u, u) > 0, it follows from (1) above that g[q-c] divides q-c; this, together with the previous sentence's conclusion, implies that gcd(q-c, z) = dz for some positive integer d.  Similarly we get gcd(c, z) = ez for some positive integer e.  Finally, these last two facts, together with the fact that adding two numbers that share a common factor preserves that factor, imply that gcd(q-c+c = q, z) >= z >= 2 -- but this contradicts the earlier conclusion that gcd(q, z) = 1.  Thus no such q can exist, and the bounded version of the algorithm is correct for all aperiodic chains.  It is thus also trivially correct for all periodic chains.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this effort. 1) Matrix A is basically adjacency matrix. I understand A^k represents the number of k-length walk. The eigenvalue is just used for the ease to compute exponent. You still need to multiply with the matrix of eigenvector M and its inverse to get the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues V^k=M^(-1)*A^k*M. The problem is the diagonalization only guaranteed if A is symmetric matrix. If the eigenvalues are not distinct, the power of the matrix is incorrect because the eigenvectors does not have full rank.

Comment: 2) I tried to implement the algorithm above.The result period supposed to be d=4 in the following example, but the code below only gave d=1. Here is the Matlab code (pls check if I misunderstand your algorithm somewhere): P=[0.5 0.5   0   0 ;
       0.5 0   0.5 0 ;
       0.5 0   0   0.5 ;
       1   0   0   0 ;
       ]

n=size(P,1)
A=double(P>0)
[E,V]=eig(A)
gcd_so_far=1
for k=1:n
    s=sum(diag(V^k))
    if s>0,
        gcd_so_far=gcd(gcd_so_far,k)
%         if gcd_so_far==1
%             d=1
%             break
%         end
    end
end
if d~=1
    d=gcd_so_far
end

Comment: Diagonalising a matrix is just one way to compute eigenvalues.  If all we want is the eigenvalues (as is the case here), It's not the best way, since as you say it only works if the matrix is diagonalisable, and many matrices aren't.  OTOH the QR algorithm computes the eigenvalues of *any* matrix. (Note that *every* matrix has a full set of eigenvalues, and these can be computed, even if it is not of full rank).

Comment: Your example P matrix has 0.5 on the diagonal, so it immediately follows that its period is 1.

Comment: Maybe your confusion about diagonalisation stems from the fact that one way to efficiently compute a power of a matrix is to first diagonalise it -- but that's not what we want to do here. We don't need to compute various powers of a matrix here -- all we need is the *trace of* various powers of a matrix. We can get that via the identity I linked to, which only requires knowing the full (multi)set of eigenvalues.

Comment: what is the initial GCD_so_far? If it is 1, it gives always period of 1 regardless whether the the P is actually for period of 2 or more.

Comment: As stated in the first proof, it's initially infinite.  That is, it's initially a value x such that gcd(x, y) = y for any y whatsoever.

Comment: I updated the algorithm part to simulate this initially-infinite GCD_so_far value with a separate flag variable.

Comment: I am new here. How to accept your answer as the correct answer?

Comment: Before you do that: On p. 12 of http://cecas.clemson.edu/~shierd/Shier/markov.pdf, there is a description of a simpler and faster algorithm that computes the periodicity in time proportional to the number of transitions, i.e. in time at most O(n^2) for n states.  This is faster than my algorithm, which I believe is at least O(n^3)-time due to the QR decomposition, and avoids floating-point arithmetic.  I would definitely use it instead!

Comment: You can upvote or downvote an answer by clicking the up or down arrow near the top-left corner, and you can mark an answer as accepted by clicking the green tick mark.  Given the fact that a better algorithm exists (the one I mentioned from the PDF), I wouldn't give my answer a tick, but you could give it an upvote.  Soon I'll make another short answer containing the linked algorithm, which you could mark as accepted :)